# Trigger event (e.g. via jQuery) when handler accesses originalEvent

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I'm trying to trigger the `propertychange` event on an `input` field for a bookmarklet (the field is OpenGrok's search field).

The handler for that field is defined like this (this is the de-minified OpenGrok source):

```
function(i) {
  var h = true;
  if (i.type == "propertychange") {
    h = i.originalEvent.propertyName.toLowerCase() == "value"
  }
  if (h) {
    if (d(this).data("timeout")) {
      clearTimeout(d(this).data("timeout"))
    }
    d(this).data("timeout", setTimeout(function() {
      f._applySearchTermFilter()
    }, f.config.searchTimeout))
  }
}
```

I tried (yes, the text field has neither name nor id, just a placeholder attribute...)

```
$('input[placeholder="Click here to select project(s)"]')
   .focus()
   .val('MY-SEARCH-TEXT')
   .trigger("propertychange")
```

but that fails because the handler tries to access `event.originalEvent`, which jQuery doesn't set. **Can I somehow fake an event which has this property?**

Maybe it would alternatively be possible to go without an event and call `_applySearchTermFilter()` directly, but I also don't know how to do that, since all these functions are inside an anonymous IIFE (and `f=this`). **Is such a function exposed through `window` in any way?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, it's actually quite simple when one knows jQuery better:

```
$('input[placeholder="Click here to select project(s)"]')
    .focus()
    .val('MY-SEARCH-TEXT')
    .trigger($.Event('propertychange', {originalEvent: {propertyName: "value"}}));
```